# when you replace values in the database saving does not happen and gives an error?

Tags: php, laravel

***Controller***

```
 public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $user= User::find($request->id);
        $user_role= User_roles::find($request->user_id);
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->surname = $request->surname;
        $user->patronymic = $request->patronymic;
        $user->number = $request->number;
        $user->password = $request->password;
        $user->iin = $request->iin;
        $user->groupinvalid = $request->groupinvalid;
        $user->rank = $request->rank;
        $user->save();

        if($request->rank =='admin')
        {
            $user_role = $request->role_id=1;
        }else if ($request->rank =='oper')
        {
            $user_role = $request->role_id=3;
        }else if ($request->rank =='user')
        {
            $user_role=$request->role_id=2;
        };
        $user_role->save();
        return redirect('users');

    }
```

need to when admin changed in (`$user->rank = $request->rank;`) to
after began test if he pointed out what the significance (admin, user,
oper) were recorded changes in table `user_role` in column `role_id` in
dependence from written rank.Yaeto has done but when you save out

> (Call to a member function save() on integer)

***model(User_role.php)***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User_roles extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'user_role';

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role','id','role_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting `$user_role` to an integer: `$user_role = $request->role_id = 1;`. That integer doesn't have a `->save()` method (That question is hard to understand, at least for me)

Comment: kerbholz then what to write for it to work

Comment: how does that help?

Comment: the name of the column where the number (1,2,3) role_id should go in the user_role table

Answer (score 0):

It has to be somthing like this

```
    if($request->rank =='admin')
    {
        $user_role->role_id = 1;
    }else if ($request->rank =='oper')
    {
        $user_role->role_id = 3;
    }else if ($request->rank =='user')
    {
        $user_role->role_id = 2;
    };
 $user_role->save();
```

Comment: @poznovashka what are you getting in this line ` $user_role= User_roles::find($request->user_id);`? What is value of `$user_role`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code :

```php
     if($request->rank =='admin')
        {
            $user_role->role_id = 1;
        }else if($request->rank =='oper')
        {
            $user_role->role_id = 3;
        }else if ($request->rank =='user')
        {
            $user_role->role_id = 2;
        };
     $user_role->save();
```